# Internet doesn't work when enable local network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

We have the following network setup:

```
A) Router IP 192.168.51.49
B) Windows Server 2008 R2 with dual NIC:
    Lan A) WAN interface (192.168.51.50) ( Used for internet)
    Lan B) LAN interface (192.168.30.228) ( used for local connectivity )
```

When I keep both LAN Enabled than my internet doesn't work, but if I disable my local LAN then internet works fine.

How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to do routing on my server

Please find the below attached route print result

```
C:\Users\Administrator>route print
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.51.49     192.168.51.50    276
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.30.227    192.168.30.228    266
    192.168.30.224  255.255.255.240         On-link      192.168.30.228    266
    192.168.30.228  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.30.228    266
    192.168.30.239  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.30.228    266
     192.168.51.48  255.255.255.240         On-link       192.168.51.50    276
     192.168.51.50  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.51.50    276
     192.168.51.63  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.51.50    276
         127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link           127.0.0.1    306
         127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link           127.0.0.1    306
   127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link           127.0.0.1    306
      202.56.230.5  255.255.255.255     192.168.51.49     192.168.51.50     21
      202.56.230.6  255.255.255.255     192.168.51.49     192.168.51.50     21
    192.168.26.124  255.255.255.255     192.168.51.49     192.168.51.50     21
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link           127.0.0.1    306
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.51.50    276
         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.30.228    266
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link           127.0.0.1    306
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.51.50    276
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.30.228    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.30.227  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.51.49  Default
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Only glanced through, but for a start, only specify a gateway on the WAN interface

Comment: What subnet are your computers on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default Gateway for the 192.168.30.x network has a lower metric than the Default Gateway for the 192.168.51.x network so the server is trying to get to the internet through the 192.168.30.x network. Remove the Default Gateway settings on that NIC and that should fix the problem.

AFAIK, Windows hosts have always and continue to only support a single Default Gateway.

Comment: Hi Joe, we have two NIC with two default Gateway, if we will not use local network gateway than we will not able to connect with our local network . Actually this server is our notes traveler server & its needs to connect with notes server as well as internet if we will not use gateway of local network than we unable to connect our notes server

Comment: A host doesn't need a DG to communicate on a directly connected (local) network. The server has an ip address on each network, it does not need a DG to communicate on each of those networks. It needs a DG (by definition) to communicate beyond those networks, and it should only have one DG.